# [CodeIgniter]: Delay time before executing redirect function in controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to delaying execute redirect function to show the alert message. I've already used the sleep function but the result is it's just delaying before calling the method from view. not execute some line on the method, delay, and execute the next line.

This is my code:

```
    if($thisJumlah != 0) {
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("Warning! The role you are to going delete has some employees")';
        echo '</script>';

        sleep(3);
        redirect('role');
    }
    else
    {
        $this->modelapp->delete($tableName, $idName, $thisID);
        redirect('role');
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is cleaner to do this with javascript:

```
if($thisJumlah != 0) {
    echo '<script language="javascript">' .
     'alert("Warning! The role you are to going delete has some employees");' .
     'setTimeout(function(){ window.location.href = "/role"; }, 3000);' .
     '</script>';
}
else
{
    $this->modelapp->delete($tableName, $idName, $thisID);
    redirect('role');
}
```

So first you alert your message then with **setTimeout** you will delay redirection for 3000 ms (3s) to your url "/role".

Answer (score 0):

php `sleep()` function make delay in execution of whole program. So your program is waiting for 3 seconds and than its getting executed from top of script (Javascript is also getting executed after wait).

You can use header function as below:

```
header( "refresh:3; url=your_url_here" );
```

More about sleep function http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php